# Laravel 5.2 validate existence of array values

Tags: php, laravel-5

Using Laravel, I have the following `$header` array:

```
[0] => var1
[1] => var2
[2] => var3
[3] => ...
```

And I need to validate that each of the values exist. Is there a more efficient way than

```
if (in_array('var1', $header) && in_array('var2', $header)...
```

I have 15 of these to check for as part of columns in a CSV file import.

Thanks

Comment: Just use a `foreach` instead of chaining `&&`.

Comment: Your `var1` and `var2` are strings?

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
$intersect = array_intersect($expectedCSVHeader, $headerRow->toArray());

if (count($intersect) != count($expectedCSVHeader)) {
    throw new Exception('Column names missing from template. Please repair the CSV file and upload it again');
}
```